# How to cut specific lines from tab separated columns?

Tags: linux, grep, cut, bioinformatics

I have a file (.gff3) that has nine columns separated by tabs.

```
##gff-version 3
##other information
0 . mRNA            1300  9000  .  +  .  ID=mrna0001;Name=sonichedgehog
1 . exon            1300  1500  .  +  .  ID=exon00001;Parent=mrna0001
2 . exon            1050  1500  .  +  .  ID=exon00002;Parent=mrna0001
3 . exon            3000  3902  .  +  .  ID=exon00003;Parent=mrna0001
4 . exon            5000  5500  .  +  .  ID=exon00004;Parent=mrna0001
5 . exon            7000  9000  .  +  .  ID=exon00005;Parent=mrna0001
```

and I am trying to get all the information from all 9 columns that have the first column starting with the number 5. My file is around 450MB.

So, I want from the entire information from columns 1-9 like this:

```
5 . exon            1300  1500  .  +  .  ID=exon00001;Parent=mrna0001
5 . exon            1050  1500  .  +  .  ID=exon00002;Parent=mrna0001
5 . exon            3000  3902  .  +  .  ID=exon00003;Parent=mrna0001
5 . exon            5000  5500  .  +  .  ID=exon00004;Parent=mrna0001
5 . exon            7000  9000  .  +  .  ID=exon00005;Parent=mrna0001
```

I have tried

```
grep '5' [FILE].gff3 >[NEWFILE].txt
```

```
cut -d'5' -f1-9 [FILE].gff3
```

Each of these is giving me my file without the information from column 1 starting wtih the number 5. So, it is doing the opposite of what I am trying to get.

Comment: If by "number" you mean "digit" then it's just `grep '^5' file`. If that's not what you wanted then provide a better example. idk why you thought `cut` might work and neither command in your question would do what you say they do (`cutting out the entire line of 5...`).

Comment: Thank you! That worked. I was just missing the ^.

Comment: @ryannellie That will match any line beginning with 5, as well as exactly 5. 50, 51, 500, etc.  To match only 5 with grep you need the tab in the regex pattern as well.  e.g. `grep $'^5\t' filename`.

Answer (score 0):

To extract all the data for chromosome 5, you may use a simple `awk` command:

```
awk -F '\t' '$1 == "5"' file.gff3 >chr5.gff3
```

To also include the GFF headers:

```
awk -F '\t' '/^#/ || $1 == "5"' file.gff3 >chr5.gff5
```

Either of these commands would read from `file.gff3` and write the extracted data to the new file `chr5.gff3`.

You could easily extend this to, for example, only include exons:

```
awk -F '\t' '/^#/ || ($1 == "5" && $3 == "exon")' file.gff3 >chr5.gff5
```